# Displaying a Jquery image list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm having a problem with the JQuery imagelist. When opening the page for the first time, the list displays correct, the image is shown, title is shown...
Pressing the back button and re-opening the page gives a normal list, no longer the jquery listview?

I'm using a DIV element in my page like this:

```
<div id="dataDiv">
  <ul data-role='listview' id='listing' data-theme='c'>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This  gets filled with information retrieved from an api call:

```
function listApiInfo() {
  clearDataDiv();
  var parsed = makeApiCallGet("http://someSite/SomeApi"); 
  i = 0;
  for (i; i < 15; i++) {
    $("#listing").append("<li>"
      + "<img src='" + imageUrl + "' alt='img' class='ui-li-thumb' />"
      + "<h1>" + parsed[i].info + "</h1>"
      + '</a></li>'
    );
  }
}
```

on loading the div, i make sure it's an empty list item:

```
function clearDataDiv() {
  $("#dataDiv").html(
    "<ul id='listing' data-role='listview' data-theme='c'></ul>");
}
```

Edit: As suggested by Wibble in the comments, i did look at the cache as the problem.
Giving the div the following option solved the problem:

```
<div id="dataDiv" onblur='window.location.reload()'>
   <ul data-role='listview' id='listing' data-theme='c'>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm still not sure if this is the most elegant solution though, it gives a blank screen for a split second.

Comment: do you get any javascript errors when inspecting your page in the browser console?

Comment: When you press "back" I believe it doesn't run through the full page lifecycle and therefore will not necessarily run all the required code on re-rendering. Have you considered looking at the cache settings of the page?

Comment: no errors in the browser console, only a mention of the completed API call: "XHR finished loading". (with the same output for the first and second try)